# How to calculate $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin(2k-1)x $?

Tags: trigonometry, summation

How do i calculate $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin(2k-1)x $, using $e^{i*x}=cos(x) + i*sin(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\sum_{k=1}^n e^{(2k-1)ix}$ is a geometric series.

Comment: With formula for geometric series, i need to have exponent $k$, so i need to transform it somehow. My idea is, that it should look like this:

$e^{-ix} \sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{2ix^{k}}$